# How can I disable app drawer in Android 12?

Tags: home-screen, app-drawer, home-screen-folders

I’m on a Samsung S20 5G, Android 12 (just moved to this phone).
On my old phone which ran android 8.1 (I don’t remember the exact model, but it was a phone from Huawei), In the Display settings I could disable the app drawer and make all the apps show on the main Home Screen.
I’ve been looking around in settings and I just can’t seem to find an option that lets me disable the app drawer.
Do I have to drag all the folders and apps in the drawer to the Home Screen for it to go? Or is there a simpler option in settings?

Comment: "*In the Display settings I could disable the app drawer and make all the apps show on the main Home Screen.*" possibly some customization done by Huawei because there's no such feature on stock Android 12. Some Samsung devices have [Easy mode](https://www.samsung.com/au/support/mobile-devices/using-easy-mode/), though I don't know if it's similar to what you want. Otherwise, 3rd-party home screen app might have such feature (though I don't know), or lastly, manually drag all the folders and apps from the drawer.

Comment: Do a web search with this query: "iOS like launchers for Android". Try the launcher apps you find there. One of them might fit your bill.

Comment: @Firelord Thanks for the suggestion! I’d rather not use a launcher though, since I really like how Android 11 looks with One UI 4. If I was desperate, I would probably use it.

Comment: @AndrewT. I was thinking of using easy mode, but it also disables many other things that I do like about android, so I’d rather not use it.